# Convert pdf to text python error

Tags: python, pdftotext

I want to convert pdf to text in specified directory

this is the code I tried

```
import os
import subprocess

def pdftotext(pdf):
    # insert your code here
    basename, _ = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pdf))
    subprocess.call(['pdftotext', '-enc', 'UTF-8',
                 pdf, os.path.join('c:\pdf\pydf\data', basename + '.txt')])

pdftotext("C:\\pdf\\pydf\\pdfs\\ipm.pdf")
with open(os.path.join('c:\\pdf\\pydf\\data', 'ipm.txt')) as infile:
   print(infile.read(1000))
```

but it get error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/pdf/browser.py", line 10, in <module>
pdftotext("C:\\pdf\\pydf\\pdfs\\ipm.pdf")
File "C:/pdf/browser.py", line 8, in pdftotext
pdf, os.path.join('c:\pdf\pydf\data', basename + '.txt'), '-'])
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 537, in call
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my post

Comment: The system cannot find the file specified (c:

Comment: File not found. "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: I'm sure that the location file is correct and the file that i want to convert is there

Comment: Then the path to the file must be wrong. Try printing the path before using it.

Comment: I don't think `pdftotext` is on your PATH. I reproduced the behaviour on my system.

Comment: Thanks @PeterWood I just locate the pdftotext in my PATH and now is working :D

Answer (score 0):

The path to the file is incorrect, instead of C:\pdf\pydf\pdfs\ipm.pdf use 
os.path.join('c:', 'pdfs', 'pdfs', 'ipm.pdf')